# Heroku app crashing immediately after deployment

Tags: python, heroku, crash, dyno

I am running a single clock dyno for my app but it crashes immediately after successful build.
Error message -

```
Build succeeded
heroku[clock.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[clock.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command `python3 clock.py`
heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[clock.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[clock.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

The error is then repeated all over again.

clock.py-

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler   
sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone="UTC")
def job_1(): 
    print("Reached Here") 
sched.add_job(job_1,trigger='interval', seconds=150)
```

Procfile -

```
clock: python3 clock.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to include `sched.start()`

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your `Procfile`

```
clock: python clock.py
```

Heroku uses `3.9.6` as default but you can change this if needed (see [Specifying Python version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version))

Comment: No, the  log on Heroku website is exactly the same .